# Can you change the number of items that are scrolled in a multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a multiselect on my page with a height set on it so that 5 items are visible. I have also set the size attribute of the select to be 5. However on some machines when they scroll using the mouse wheel more than 5 items are scrolled at a time so they miss some out. Is this purely determined by the mouse settings of the computer or is there a way to specify how many lines should be scrolled each time so that it's the same for everyone? A jquery solution might be ok if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

In default select you can't do this. Try replace select with jQuery plugin. [Google can help](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=custom%20multiple%20select%20jquery&oq=cu&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j69i61j0l3.1524j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). User can change this parameter for self: Start | Control Panel | Mouse | Wheel | Scrolling.